# MySQL Unknown column 'Extent1.ID' in 'on clause' with EF6

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, collections, entity-framework-6

I have the following class structure

```
public class Question
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime On { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime On { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public List<Star> Stars { get; set; }
    public List<Reply> Replys { get; set; }
}
public class Reply
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime On { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
public class Star
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get the question details, for that i use

```
Question question = dbContext.Questions.Include("Answers.Replys.Member").Include("Answers.Stars.Member").SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == Id);
```

But this statement gives me an exception

Unknown column 'Extent1.ID' in 'on clause'

If I remove one Include or remove Member from any Include it works fine.

I have a similar problem with MySQL EF 6 which is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738325/fetch-the-entire-nested-model-in-a-single-call-ef6-mysql). MySQL version using is MySQL 6.9.7.0.

Comment: did you got solution for it ? if yes can you please share